# Where to manufacture a 3D wood puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-creation

I have a design for a puzzle I want to develop. It requires fairly good accuracy when cutting the pieces which have complicated shapes, although they all are made of equal size cubes.

Eventually I would like to market it, so I am interested in mass production (meaning a few hundred).

Comment: Well, there _is_ an Area 51 proposal for [woodworking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61927/woodworking?referrer=HmYeJ-1ZyJtEcOlY9VldUw2) that could use a couple of questions upvoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shop bot. http://www.shopbottools.com/ It is probably the best tool for making accurate wood cuts, and they are available in many makerspaces.If you are interested in mass production, get started by using Kickstarter.http://kickstarter.com/